# How to resolve import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

As we know google-play-services are divided in to different small classes.(screesnshot 1 ) I am trying to find the suitable class for import **com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback**; but cannot able to find that. If someone know which class will use or know the process to solve that then please let me know. I am using eclipse not andoroid studio.

thanks[image]

Comment: It seems you have the same error with this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262213/import-com-google-android-gms-common-api-googleapiclient-cannot-be-resolved), it's been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback` is part of **play-services-basement**.  Since each of these components is packaged up in an .aar file, you'll need to manually process them to use Eclipse.  (Just out of curiosity, why not use Android Studio?)

There a two steps involved in this processing. The contents of the arr file are listed here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format.  First is to unpack the aar into a directory that you'll use as a library in Eclipse.  .aar Files are just zipped, so they can be unpacked using `jar xvf <filename>.aar`. Once that is done you can list the contents of classes.jar and find the class you are looking for (`jar tvf classes.jar`).

The second step is to look at the metadata and determine if another aar file is a dependency.  This is in a `.pom` file that contains the dependency information.  play-services-basement is typically not included directly, but is a common dependency for other .aar files.

Comment: haha. thank you.  I tried base but not basement library.  Actually I am unity developer and seldom work on android native so eclipse is fine for me.